# Duplicate N-times Sling resouce

Tags: copy, resources, sling, jcr

I have a sling `JCR` resource tree, there is resource folder named `test` and file named `testFile` inside. `testFile` have own structure(subnodes/files) inside, I want copy all of them(with subnodes)

```
/root
   |_test
       |_testFile
```

For server test I want to make copy N-times of this file. Any idea how to do it using `ResourceResolver` ?

I need to have as below:

```
/root
   |_test
       |_testFile
       |_testFile1
           ...
       |_testFileN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own utility that does that and use the `copy()` method of the ResourceResolver, see the docs https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#copy-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: I checked the `copy()` but there is only `copy(from, to)` and main question is how to create copy in the same place, using the same file with only other name

Comment: @CoderZ you're right, I was using a different utility method, not the OOTB `copy`. There is no OOTB option for this, you have to create your own method of "cloning" nodes.